# Anylogic dynamic Location of arrival for carSource

Tags: anylogic

Is there any idea how to set location of arrival of a car dynamically and during code. For example imagine that we have 20 parking lots and I don't want to draw 20 carSources for each one. Only one carSource and determining the location dynamically is my goal. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re making this a function, I suggest this:

1. create a collection of type ArrayList that stores ParkingLots. Manually add all your parking lots as below:
   [image]
2. create the function `getRandomParkingLot` that returns a ParkingLot. Set the code so it pulls a random object from the collection as below:
   [image]

Comment: Pleasure :-) please upvote the answer as "useful" ;-)

Comment: I voted, but because of my low reputation score it is not publicly depicted.

Comment: this is the message shown after I vote: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: But my score improves nonetheless ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple: just use the dynamic property of the CarSource initial location as below. You need to click on the little "=" symbol left of the normal selection object and type code as below:
[image]

Comment: And how if we want to do this in a function? should we write a function which returns a parkingLot?